# va_arg( , double) return each time an invalid value

Tags: c, arguments

When I run this sample program using va_arg(ap,double), I found va_arg return invalid data, as 0 instead of 3 or 1.2 instead of 1, such that if I pass integer value without .00 instead of double format it get a garbage data (ie 3 instead of 3.00)!!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
void func(int s){
    printf("%s: %d\n",__func__,s);
}

void var(int count,...){
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap,count);
    double a = va_arg(ap,double);
    printf("%f\n",a);
    va_end(ap);

}

void main(void ) {
    printf("%s,%d,%s\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,__DATE__);
    func(__LINE__);
    var(1,3);
    var(1,1.2);
    var(1,1);

}
```

The Output is:

```
try.c,24,Sep 25 2012
func: 25
0.000000
1.200000
1.200000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variadic functions (that is, functions which take a variable number of arguments indicated by the ellipsis (`...`) parameter) have weak typing in C.  Except in the case of certain special functions like `printf` and `scanf`, the compiler makes no effort to verify that you're passing the correct types of arguments to them.

In your case, the function is expecting a `double` parameter, but you're trying to pass in an `int`.  The compiler does not do any promotion here from `int` to `double`, so undefined behavior results.  You need to always pass in a `double` value here, either as an explicit `double` constant value such as `1.0`, or perform the conversion using a typecast.

Comment: I don't know about other compiler but at least GNU GCC warns you (if you use -Wall) that you are passing the wrong arguments to `printf` and `scanf` functions.  However if you write a real `printf/scanf` wrapper then gcc stops warning you there. So `printf/scanf` seems to be a special case anyway

Comment: @Pablo: Yes, that's right.  If you have your own functions that act like `printf`/`scanf` wrappers, you can have GCC check their arguments by declaring them with the [`format` attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bformat_007d-function-attribute-2555).

Comment: ' Except in the case of certain special functions like printf and scanf, the compiler makes no effort to verify that you're passing the correct types of arguments to them.' -- The compiler makes no effort for **any** function unless you tell it to -- there is no "special case". gcc does type checks for printf and scanf because those functions are declared with an `__attribute__((...))` that says to; anyone can (and should) declare their own variadic functions similarly.

Comment: @adam: damn, didn't know about that. When I wrote once a microkernel I had to be very careful because of this. If I then would have known that, a lot of trouble could have been spoted when compiling. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @JimBalter: Yes, `printf` et al are declared with `__attribute__` in the GCC header files, but they actually are still special beyond that -- if you don't include `<stdio.h>` and instead declare `printf` yourself, GCC will still check the argument types anyways.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that (obviously, and shouldn't have spoken without verifying) but see it now in the format attributes link. I think you should add that link and a discussion of it to your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I am trying to eliminate the usage of Variadic function, as it very week as you said, try to put different arguments in function call before (,...) and you will no what that mean.
Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Well, `3` and `1` are integers and not doubles. Their binary representation of these numbers is different than that of `3.0` and `1.0`.

```
var(1,3.9);
var(1,1.2);
var(1,5.7);


$ ./a 
a.c,17,Sep 25 2012
func: 18
3.900000
1.200000
5.700000
```

Comment: The OP may not be aware of or understand the notion of "binary representation".