# va_arg not working with doubles

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have a function that takes a variable number of arguments, and then passes each argument to a function, depending on other factors. This is working well for most types, regardless of whether or not they are a pointer

```
func = (fmtfunc_t)dictobj(deflt, tok);
dat = func(va_arg(lst, void *));
```

where `fmtfunc_t` is defined as

```
typedef char * (*fmtfunc_t)(void *);
```

This method works, for example, with functions like the following

```
char *examp1(int i) {
    // i points to the correct integer value
}
char *examp2(char *s) {
    // s points to the correct string value
}
```

However, it does not work when the argument is a `double`

```
char *examp3(double d) {
    // d is 0
}
```

I am aware of [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12587860/va-arg-double-return-each-time-an-invalid-value) with `va_arg` and double promotion, but I don't believe that this is the root of my problem. I call the function like this

```
func(23.4);
```

As you can see, the argument is a `double` literal, so I don't believe I should be concerned with promotion issues.

Why is `va_arg` returning an incorrect value for `double`s, but not for any other type? Am I encountering some kind of undefined behavior and getting lucky with types other than `double`?

Comment: If `i` "points" to an integer for `examp1`, there is something wrong already. The function expects an integer, not a pointer. Provide a [mcve] with the declaration of your variadic function. As give, you cannot call it like that, because you are lacking an named argument.

Comment: The problem isn't with the `va_arg`. The problem is with your use of `fmtfunc_t`. This is a violation of 6.5.2.2(9) "If the function is defined with a type that is not compatible with the type (of the expression) pointed to by the expression that denotes the called function, **the behavior is undefined**."

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks for that, I'll have to change the way I do this then. (at)Olaf I tried to make the examples as brief as possible, so I'd add more, but I'm not sure that it's necessary now that I know this is undefined behavior.

Comment: Actually, looking at it again, the problem is also in the `va_arg`. 7.15.1.1(2): "If *type* is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions), **the behavior is undefined**, except for the following cases [none of which apply]." My guess for the reason you're seeing the problem just with `double` is that `int` and `void*` are passed the same way (in GP registers) but `double` is passed in an FP register.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not going to work. You can't simply fetch an argument as any type and expect that to work.

Comment: @FUZxxl I now made cases for `double`, `int`, and other primitives; am I correct in assuming that any pointer can be fetched as `void *`, or does it need to be specific to the type? eg. `char *`, `int *`

Comment: @ChrisLoonam That's not guaranteed to work but it's one of the things that work fine in practice and are very unlikely to break.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam 7.15.1.1(2) quoted above says that the *type* must match the actual type, with the exception that `void*` can be used interchangeably with `char*`. Other pointer mixtures are not allowed. There exist computers where `char*` and `int*` are not interchangeable. (They aren't used much, but they do exist.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Ok, thanks for doing this research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, as pointed out by @RaymondChen, @Olaf, and @FUZxxl in the comments, was that, by calling the functions with arguments that had types that were incompatible with the declarations

```
char *examp(int i);

fmtfunt_t func = examp;
func(va_arg(lst, void *)); //called with an argument of void*, but the parameter is of type int
```

I was causing undefined behavior. I solved this by fetching the arguments as their appropriate types

```
double arg = va_arg(lst, double);
```

Rather than trying to use `void *` as a catch-all.